# Как правильно настроить роутинг в Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь настроить роутинг в Gateway в properties прописываю адрес и куда перенаправлять, не могу понять логику работы.

```
server:
 port: 8081
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
   gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: servicetest
          uri: http://localhost:8080/
          predicates:
            - Path=/services/**
        - id: service-student
          uri: http://localhost:8082/
          predicates:
           - Path=/**
```

ServiceTest

```
    spring.application.name=ServiceTest
    server.port=8080
```

@RestController
public class TestController {

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(){
    return "Controller is work from " + this.getClass().getName().toString();
}
```

}

service-student

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

server.port=8082
spring.application.name=service-student

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TeacherController {

    @Autowired
    TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @GetMapping("/teachers")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Teacher>> findAllTeachers(){
        List<Teacher> groups = teacherRepository.findAll();
        if(groups.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(groups, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(groups,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

При доступе через `http://localhost:8081/teachers`, все ок, возвращается JSON с нужного сервиса(id service-student). А вот если делать `Path=/services/**` и пробовать достучаться `http://localhost:8081/services/hello` доступа нет. Как правильно создать конфиг?

Comment: а сервис какой-либо на 8080 поднят?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/services/hello что-то возвращает? Также попробуйте временно убрать второй роут(id service-student)

Comment: Ну то есть проблема решена? А то многа букаф)) А лучше приведите код в вопросе(код маппингша контроллеров с портами) Судя по второму контроллеру у вас не хвататет маппинга для `/services/`. Если вам он не нужен на втором сервисе - то вы должны использовать фильтр `rewritepath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, если имеем два запроса

http://localhost:8081/teachers

http://localhost:8081/services/hello

И два сервиса, соответвенно

http://localhost:8082/teachers

http://localhost:8080/hello

То настройка будет выглядеть вот таким образом

```
server:
 port: 8081
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
   gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: servicetest
          uri: http://localhost:8080/
          predicates:
            - Path=/services/{segment}
          filters: 
            - SetPath=/{segment}
        - id: service-student
          uri: http://localhost:8082/
          predicates:
           - Path=/**
```

Хитрость в подмене пути через фильтр [SetPath](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_setpath_gatewayfilter_factory)

Или можно не менять настройку, но тогда изменить маппинг в сервисе, добавив на класс аннотацию `@RequestMapping("/services")`